# Random folders appear on all my drives

Tags: windows, desktop

So I have various desktops and all have more or less the same issue. In the root of each drive there are randomly named folders generated.
Names like:

```
2b174a7b6cd269132e8dd780
52aebd6aec88ceb00badbc
32601669e81d70e5b9c7c8
ae888118d1365c5a165784ed221b20
```

So the only common thing seems to be that they are all hexadecimal, but even the lenght of the names are different.

There is a minor difference in Win10:

1. For Win 7/8/8.1 the folders are empty.
2. On Win 10 the folders contain a folder called `SandBox` which is empty.

The majority of the folders can be deleted without any issues, but some of them can't even with administrator rights.

I spent the last two days on google but couldn't solve this. I read that many of the people thinks that this is due to Windows Update. If that was true why my non-system partitions, external hard drives, usb pendrives are also affected?

I have to mention that all of my machines are affected regardless of their OS, location, user, etc. They run different anti-virus/anti-malware tools. None of them shows any sign of any infection.

What the heck is that?

Comment: These folders are harmless.  Windows Update will place the data required to install data on the largest drive it finds.  This has been the default behavior since the dawn of time.

Comment: So it is normal in the root of the drive and not somewhere in user temp or c:\temp or anywhere else? Also what if i have these folders on c: AND d: on the same machine? Also i haven't seen this till last week and I'm workink in desktop/server support since ages. How is this possible?

Comment: I have no idea how you don't know that Windows Update will place temporary folders on the largest drive connected to the system.  The folders are harmless though, if you want, feel free to delete them.

Comment: I know it places temp folders but not in the root of the drive...

Comment: Also like I mentioned in the Q there are some folders can't be deleted.

Comment: You have to take ownership of the folders before you can delete them.

Comment: OK. To be honest the main issue is that this messes up the whole folder structure. It's ugly and ridiculous to have in the root. And again till last week there were no such folders there. For sure.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like Visual Studio windows updates. Have you got that installed on your machine?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/random-files-being-created-in-c-unable-to-delete/84d2b5c4-54ea-4c6f-94e3-2649c61becdf?auth=1

I see that on a lot of users PC who has Visual studio installed.

Comment: Visual Studio is installed only on my Win10 machine, but not on the rest. And again, if it's VS then why these folders appear on my D: drive for e.g.?

Comment: Also on the link you mentioned the guy has a number of folders in these, but not me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @fishmong3r I've seen it do that on my machine as well when I have a larger D drive. They tend to appear after Windows updates and I just delete them.